# How to start a shared X server for remote, non-forwarded use?

Tags: xorg

I am not sure I am asking the right question, so here's what I actually want to do:

I have a server that has a screen connected to it and no other devices. It is running an SSH server.

I would like Alice to be able to connect to the server and run a command as "staff" to show a picture on the screen. For example...

`ssh server sudo -u 'staff' gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///path/to/image.png`

Alice goes home, and the image is still showing. Bob comes in, and decides he wants a different image:

`ssh server sudo -u 'staff' gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///path/to/other.png`

How does the X server need to be started and configured to meet my needs? Only the "staff" user will need to manipulate the display.

I know that I can start the server on boot using xinit and run a program of my choice. What program should I run? What should it do? Are there environment variables I will need to pass around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a common linux environment X server is using MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 protocol to authorize access to the display.  Any user who wants to access the display needs to have a correct *cookie* (usualy stored in ~/.Xauthority file).  Normally the cookie is generated by a display manager (login screen).  If you are starting X server from your custom scripts you have to generate the cookie yourself, store it in an *authority file* and inform the server about that file.

You can use command `mcookie` to generate the cookie and add it to the authority file with `xauth`:

```
# touch /home/staff/.Xauthority
# xauth -f /home/staff/.Xauthority add :0 . $(mcookie)
```

Prameter `-f /home/staff/.Xauthority` tells `xauth` to use authority file of the **staff** user. `:0` is the display name.  The dot (`.`) specifies the MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 protocol. `mcookie` is from [util-linux](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) package.

Now if you execute:

```
# xauth -f /home/staff/.Xauthority list
```

you should see something like:

```
server/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c61bdc0b88cf0cb376e1b29647a8c4d6
```

When you log-in as **staff** user you should see the same output *without* -f parameter:

```
$ xauth list
server/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c61bdc0b88cf0cb376e1b29647a8c4d6
```

If not check that `XAUTHORITY` environment variable is either undefined or it is set to "/home/staff/.Xauthority".

Start the X server with `-auth` parameter:

```
# X -auth /home/staff/.Xauthority
```

Now **staff** user can access the display `:0`.  The only thing that's left is to set the environment variable `DISPLAY` - this can be done via `sudo` parameter.  So when you ssh to **server** and execute a command that shows an image as **staff** user then it should be displayed.  Using ImageMagick as suggested by L. Levrel the command would be:

```
# ssh server sudo -u staff DISPLAY=:0 display -window root /path/to/image.png
```

**Note** you do not have to use **staff** user.  You can create authority file in a common location (e. g. /var/tmp/xauthority) and set environment variable `XAUTHORITY` for **Alice** and **Bob** to that path.

Other alternative is to "distribute" the cookie to **Alice's** and **Bob's** authority files (this is actually similar to what display managers are doing):

```
# xauth -f /var/tmp/xauthority extract - :0 | xauth -f /home/alice/.Xauthority merge
# xauth -f /var/tmp/xauthority extract - :0 | xauth -f /home/bob/.Xauthority merge
```

This way **Alice** and **Bob** does not have to do `sudo staff` in order to access the display.

**Note** that if you have more X servers running you have to use different display name than `:0` in the above commands (for example: `:1`, `:2`, etc.).

Comment: One would think that authorization should be valid only for specific **instance** of X server but this answer suggests one can *generate authorization* even without X server running…

Answer (score 0):

If you have ImageMagick installed, you can use:

```
display -window root /path/to/image.png
```

See [the documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#window). There are [plenty of options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#option). You will probably need at least `-display`.